# PDO exec() and unbuffered queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, laravel-4

I have a few triggers which are executed using PHP PDO . 
I am using Laravel framework .

I am using solydK OS with the latest Xampp installed. The triggers are giving the following errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.'
```

After some tweaking, i tried executing the queries with `PDO::exec()` , and it worked!

So, the result is: it works with `PDO::exec()` but fails with `PDO::query` and `PDO::prepare()`

I want to know the reason behind this, does `PDO::exec()` do something special or may be
Laravel has some special configuration.

Note1: I have already tried solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066714/pdo-cannot-execute-queries-while-other-unbuffered-queries-are-active) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031334/pdoexception-with-message-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2014-cannot-execute)
Note2: It works perfectly if simple PDO is used instead of Laravel DB wrapper .
Note3: PDO is using mysqlnd driver